# Recarregar conteúdo while ao dar Submit

Tags: php, javascript, html, odbc

Tenho a necessidade de quando carregar todo o conteúdo definido na consulta do banco a cada while e preencher os campos e dar o submit, ele grave no banco e recarregue somente aquele loop me trazendo os dados preenchidos do banco novamente. 
Assim quando estiver lançando informações e gravando no banco, ele me atualize quais estão preenchidas e futuramente quando carregar a pagina outro dia vou saber quais estão preenchidos tambem.

Exemplo do código:

```
    while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {

    $sqlConfirma = "SELECT inf_km, km FROM dba.km
    WHERE dba.km.id= ".$id."";

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<form name='InsertBanco' action='executar.php' target='_blank' method='post'>
        <td><input type='text' name='km_op' value='".odbc_result($sqlConfirma, "inf_km")."'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='km' value='".odbc_result($sqlConfirma, "km")."'></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='InsertBanco' value='Inserir'></td>
        </form>         
        }
echo "</tr>"
```

Este e somente um exemplo do código, não e ele em si, já que uso muitos outros campos.
A solução poderia ser Javascript e Jquery também.

Comment: Explique a necessidade melhor dessa interação, pois, além de ter problemas com dados de grande porte, ficou muito abrangente a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc podia meter uma confirmação sem ser no campo usando esse codigo mas com uma condiçao, que ele so mostrasse quando o submit tivesse sido clicado:

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
    $sqlConfirma = "SELECT * FROM dba.km WHERE dba.km.id = $id";
    mysqli_query((coneccao), $sqlConfirma;

    echo 'Adicionado com sucesso á base de dados: ' . $inf_km . ', ' . $km . '.';
```

}

Mas se preferir dessa maneira pode fazelo introduzindo esse codigo no value ou mesmo no placeholder para nao ter q apagar para introduzir um novo.

Outra forma seria no fim de os dados estarem guardados, gerar um link GET para uma outra página (ou para a mesma) com os dados inseridos.
Se vc optar por fazer isso basta criar um header no final do php assim:

```
header(Location:'(nome_do_ficheiro)?inf_km=' . '$(inf_km)' . '&amp;km=' . $(km) . '&amp;id=' . $id');
```

Meti entre parentesis o q nao sabia ja que sao variaveis e ficheiros q vc teria de criar.

Espero ter ajudado,
MDC

Comment: Irmão vou ter que alterar algumas coisas ai, mas ajudou demais, vc me deu um caminho que acredito que vai dar certo. Eu dando o submit pra a mesma pagina ele ja a recarrega e me confirma, mas como e muita informação ele vai ter que varrer todo o banco novamente, então por isso queria recarregar o loop. mais vc me deu uma alternativa legal. Obrigado.

Comment: Ah, uma duvida quem sabe pode me ajudar. Como faço dentro de um value lendo em php colocar uma condição de comparação? Ja tentei: `echo "<inpu....  value=' ".if(condição){}." ' ";` Mais não da certo. Não queria alterar tudo em html denovo. `value=" <?php echo if() ?>"`

Comment: @WillianCoqueiro Faça essa condição antes em uma variável ou ternário. Ficaria mais fácil. Quanto à sua dúvida, se deu certo, marque depois como resposta certa.

Comment: Ou pode meter o echo dentro da condicao: if(...){ echo '...'} else{echo'...'}